# how to change query string parameters with name using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am passing parameters from one page to another page in PHP here is the code :-

```
<a href="index.php?product.php&category_id=<? echo $Getrow['id'];?>" target="_blank">Detail</a>
```

Now when i clicked on detail link it shows product page but at this page category_id is showing for example category_id=15 thus i don't want to show it rather then this id i want show category name using .htaccess
please help me

I want its answer because when we pass query string like example.com/index.php?category_id=15&product_id=13 at this time someone can change it like example.com/index.php?category_id=156546565464654&product_id=13546545484 I don't want this thing.

Comment: This is not how htaccess works.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer means ?

Comment: Meaning, this won't work, unless you are hard-coding all your category names in your htaccess file. Better take care of this through PHP.

Comment: @GolezTrol for your kind information Mr. GolezTrol this is not hard coded i looked at many websites that do the same thing as what i want i looked many tutorials but i was unable to understand.

Comment: Biting the hand that feeds you. I don't think you are in any position to call people here 'beginners', and if you think it's so simple, at least show *some* effort to solve it. Or are you just trolling, like in your other question?

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar.
When I create a link, I create the link in from of a text using variables, like `<a href="category-15">click me</a>`

Then in .taccess I do this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ search.php?id=$2
```

and then the link `http://example.com/category-15` takes me to `http://example.com/search?id=15`

I think, you can change the variables in the htaccess for your needs, you just need to use $1, $2, $3 etc for replacement.
I hope this helps.

EDIT: I edited the example url, for consistency.

Comment: why you write here id=$2 here $2 means ?

Comment: ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) is the first regular expression (wildcard if you want) for changing the text and ([0-9]+) is the second. I pass a number in my text link, so I need to know that number. If I would use like http://example.com/category?id=15&product=34, then category would be $1 and product $2, but the wildcard must be partitioned the same way, so you would probably do something like `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)` for `category-15-product-34`. The ^is the start of a string, the $ is the end of a string and has nothing to do with $1 etc.

Comment: @ Hunnenkoenig Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=product_details&pid=$1    nothing happen ......... :-(

Comment: You need to understand that my example is tailored for my needs. You need to change the rewrite rule on your needs. I for my part put my links together from a title and a number I get from php as a variable. So my link would look like `myexample.com/this-is-a-very-nice-book-15` (I add the hyphens between the words by replacing space in code), but actually I want to show `myexample.com/search?id=15` now my link has two parts. A text part (which can also contain numbers) and a number part, which is always a number for the ID number I actually look for. -> ->

Comment: So my rewrite rule is ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) for the text part and ([0-9]+) for the number part. Two parts, two sets of wildcard. It seems you need to do the same. Because the link itself is your part 1 and the actual id is part two. So you need ` ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=product_details&pid=$2` and pass a link as `myexample.com/myniceproduct-15`

Comment: But you need to reference the second wildcard with $2 because you want to use that. The $2 actually takes the original number that was passed. `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` = $1 - `([0-9]+)` = $2

Comment: example.com/index.php?category_id=15&product_id=13 would be `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ example.com/index.php?category_id=$2&product_id=$4`

and that would give `example.com/mycategory-15-my-product-13` and nobody could change that, because no matter what he adds to the url, it always will take you to the url YOU passed in your code and nowhere else.

Comment: Of course you must format your links as `mycategory` and `my-product` or whatever you want, but in accordance to your rewrite rule.