# htaccess mod_rewrite rules combination issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm so newbie in apache, so it's a basic question but I couldn't solve this using another questions or links.

I tried to change my `URL` using `.htaccess` and I had two purposes;

1. hide **`.php`** extension
2. change some queryString from ***`somefile.php?id=bar`*** to `somefile/id/bar` which `bar` is a number or mixed string like **`T51-3`**.

   My queryString is `http://localhost/payment/theme/ticket?id=770314` that I want change it to ***`http://localhost/payment/theme/ticket/id/770314`*** or

   ***`http://localhost/payment/theme/ticket/770314`***

I found this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]


## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

in [stackoverflow.com/this_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions)

This was working nice but didn't solve my second issue.

So, I searched for a while in this site and others and did find some sample codes like this one :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ ticket.php?id=$2
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ticket.php?url=$1 [L]
```

and etc...

but none of these didn't work for me.

Some of them will make the server done and some don't have any affect at all.
Would you please guide me to right way...

I looked at these questions:

[htaccess rewrite for query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string)

[how to change query string parameters with name using .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392487/how-to-change-query-string-parameters-with-name-using-htaccess)

[How can I use .htaccess to hide .php URL extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions)

And these links:

http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

***UPDATE :***

This is my site strucure:
[image: site structure]

There is an htaccess for important folders, like, `forms`, `db`, `classes` etc...

All my site pages are in the `theme` folder, as you can see in the picture.

In the root htaccess, there's just two lines that auto start sessions.

And I added your code to theme's htaccess.

***`Thanks in Advance`***

Comment: Is your htaccess in root?

Comment: @Starkeen no, there's an htaccess for each folder. The htaccess that I put codes into, is inside a folder that contains all website pages...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /payment/theme/

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php\?(\w+)=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# to handle http://localhost/payment/theme/ticket/id/770314
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but unfortunatley didn't work again. :(

Comment: :-) There's not error... This code change `*/somepage.php` to `*/somepage` and that's good for me, but when I have querystrings like `somepage.php?id=123456`, I expected to be `somepage/id/123456` but the result is  `somepage?id=123456`

Comment: Thanks again... well, the url is as I expect but there's 404 error after using this code when I have querystring. `*/somepage.php` is ok but `*/somepage.php?id=123` give me 404.

Comment: yes...exactly. `http://domain.com/payment/theme/somepage.php?id=123456` will change to `http://domain.com/payment/theme/somepage/id/123456` but there's 404 error and server show: `OBJECT NOT FOUND`

Comment: Now it's ok But it seems this can't find `css` and `js` files!!! because the page will show without any style... This show just html part... And thank you again...

Comment: this situation is about queryStrings. The simple page names are OK. `*/somepage.php`  will change to `*/somepage' but `somepage/id/123456` just show html part without any style...!!!

Comment: Add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/payment/theme/" />` to resolve css/js paths